# How is root motion done in Skeletal animation

Tags: opengl, skeletal-animation, assimp

I am using Assimp library to load bone and mesh data and using basic interpolation to accomplish the animation part. Right now I want to move my character position with animation, i.e. root motion.

What I tried is just advance the position with translation value of root bone. I transformed this translation value with "world space rotation and translation matrix", which doesn't contain scale. (Do I also need to use scale matrix?)

Here's the simplified version of code: (assume all interpolation is happening in root joint)

```
 void RootBoneUpdate(float animationTime,AnimationComponent* handle)
 {
    vec3 translation = InterpolatePosition(animationTime);
    quat rotation = InterpolateRotation(animationTime);
    vec3 scale = InterpolateScaling(animationTime);

        TransformComponent transform = currentActor->GetComponent<TransformComponent>();
        RigidBodyComponent rigidBody = currentActor->GetComponent<RigidBodyComponent>();

        worldSpaceBoneTranslation = transformComponent->GetTRMatrix() * tranlsation;

//not modifying Y coordinate
        rigidBody.x = worldSpaceBoneTranslation.x; 
        rigidBody.z = worldSpaceBoneTranslation.z;
}
```

Problem: It's working, but the game actors are moving really fast.

My understanding is that the software used to create animation must have a different coordinate space with bigger scale. Do I need to again scale the worldSpaceBoneTranslation or am I doing something wrong?